How can I call an already registered launchplan in Flyte?
I am trying to fetch an already registed Flyte Launchplan or workflow but I am not able to find the relevant API. Can you please help me?
Below is the code I took from External Workflow. It contains LaunchPlan.get_or_create and I want something like LaunchPlan.fetch_latest('regression_line_workflow').
from flytekit import LaunchPlan

launch_plan = ??#LaunchPlan.get_or_create(
    regression_line_wf, "regression_line_workflow", default_inputs={"val": 7, "x": [-3, 0, 3], "y": [7, 4, -2]}
)


@workflow
def nested_regression_line_lp() -> float:
    # Trigger launch plan from within a workflow
    return launch_plan()


You can use the Flyteremote API for this. It includes a remote.fetch_launch_plan method that you could use like this:
from flytekit.remote import FlyteRemote
from flytekit.configuration import Config

# Initialize FlyteRemote
remote = FlyteRemote(
    config=Config.for_endpoint(endpoint="flyte.example.net"),
    default_project="flytesnacks",
    default_domain="development",
)


# Fetch the LaunchPlan
flyte_lp = remote.fetch_launch_plan(
    name="workflows.example.wf", version="v1", project="flytesnacks", domain="development"
)

This is somewhat covered in the docs https://docs.flyte.org/en/latest/api/flytekit/design/control_plane.html#fetching-entities
Does this helps?
